# Are all BT 4/5 dongles compatible BLE?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi to interact with devices via Bluetooth, specifically Bluetooth Low Energy.

My understanding is that this is a protocol which was introduced with BT 4 but I do not understand whether special dongles are required. None of the ones I looked at mention Bluetooth Low Energy.

Are all BT devices (specifically USB dongles) automatically compatible with BLE if they are BT 4+?

Comment: I am 90% sure, that not only does the hardware have to support BLE, the drivers have to support it.

Answer (score 0):

There are substantial technical differences between BT4.0 "classic" and BLE. (See [Bluetooth_Low_Energy: Technical_details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Technical_details) on Wikipedia) which makes them distinctly different modes of operation. A single radio *can* cater for both, but the software would have to support the different styles of connection.

From [the compatibility section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Compatibility) on that Wikipedia page:

> Bluetooth Low Energy is not backward-compatible with the previous (often called "classic") Bluetooth Basic Rate/Enhanced Data Rate (BR/EDR) protocol. **The Bluetooth 4.0 specification permits devices to implement either or both of the LE and BR/EDR systems.**

So no, BT 4.0 does not mandate or imply BLE support. Devices *can* support both, but stating support for one does not mean that support for the other is guaranteed.

Similarly for Bluetooth 5 from [Summitdata: What's new in Bluetooth 5](http://www.summitdata.com/blog/whats-new-with-bluetooth-5-0/)

> All the major enhancements in Bluetooth 5 are for the BLE radio and there is nothing new associated with the Bluetooth Classic radio.

The "Classic" Bluetooth radio and the BLE radio are still separate in Bluetooth 5, with the implication that "Bluetooth 5" means "classic bluetooth" and if BLE is stated along with Bluetooth 5 then it will be the enhanced "Bluetooth 5 BLE".